# Códigos NCM para importar em meu sistema

Tags: nfe

Oi,

Gostaria de importar a tabela completa de códigos NCM em meu sistema, mas aparentemente a receita não disponibiliza um formato amigável para ser importado (CSV, texto, inserts, etc).
  Alguém conhece alguma fonte onde posso encontrar isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que isso não é bem dentro do escopo do site, porém segue o link com o que você necessita:

https://github.com/aricaldeira/NCM/tree/master/tabelas

Comment: Oi Otto, talvez você conheça melhor.. Hoje em dia (2016) qual dos padrões (códigos oficiais de produtos/mercadorias) é o mais utilizado,  NBM, a NCM ou TIPI?

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

No site nacional da NF-e tem um arquivo excel com os códigos de NCM válidos.

[Tabela NCM](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/PORTAL/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=oqXtmaR10bY=)

Fonte: http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/PORTAL/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=oqXtmaR10bY=